# Как создать QProgressBar с double значениями?

Tags: qt

Мне требуется создать ProgressBar с градацией 0.00 до 1.00. 
Думаю можно перегрузить функцию Value() и  setMaximum(), setMinimum().

Или лучше от рисовать этот элемент заново  open_gl-ем ???

Comment: Почему бы просто не пересчитывать значения в 0; 100, например с помощью лямбда - функции?

Comment: @gbg я это вывожу на экран это число, это требование заказчика. К примеру 0.85МПа. МПа добавляются прям в редакторе а вот число 0,85 это уже тяжело.

Comment: progBar->setFormat("Your text here. "+QString::number(progress)+"%"); - это тяжело?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вы задаете вопрос, не описывая полностью свою проблему. Есть специальный топик об этом: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/Что-такое-Ошибка-молотка-или-Ошибка-xy

Comment: @gbg, `format`'ом число с плавающей точкой вывести только через сигналы-слоты получится — не самый приятный вариант... Я бы отнаследовался и перегрузил `text ()` — так ИМХО почище будет... можно даже включить в формат специальные символы для этого.

Comment: @Fat-Zer а как перегрузить text . Мы говорим о перегрузке QProgressBar -> text() ?? Точнее где почитать про отнаследование   "надеюсь это не жаргонизм" ?? Можно хотя бы наводку про отнаследование, либо пример на основании  простейшего элемента Qt.

Comment: @timob256, «отнаследоваться» — грязный жаргонизм, про наследование классов можно почитать в любом учебнике по C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросал на коленке вариант с кастомным внешнем функтором форматирования. Код абсолютно не проверялся и может содержать ошибки, но идея должна быть понятна.

```
class FormattableProgressBar: public QProgressBar {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  typedef std::function(QString(const FormattableProgressBar*)) FormatterFunc;
private:
  FormatterFunc formatter_f;
public:
  explicit FormattableProgressBar(QWidget *parent=0)
      :QProgressBar(parent) {}
  FormattableProgressBar(FormatterFunc formatter, QWidget *parent=0)
      :QProgressBar(parent), formatter_f(formatter) {}

  virtual QString text () const {
    if (formatter_f) {
      return formatter_f (this);
    } else {
      return QProgressBar::text();
    }
  }

  void setFormatter (const FormatterFunc &new_f) { formatter_f = new_f;}
  FormatterFunc formatter () const { return formatter_f;}
};
```

Использование (значения из диапазона `minimum`~`maximum` приводятся в диапазон `0.00`~`1.00`):

```
pb = new FormattableProgressBar ([](const FormattableProgressBar *pb) {
  int min = pb->minimum ();
  int max = pb->maximum ();
  double val = (double) (pb->value () - min) / (max - min);
  return QString::fromUtf8 ("%1 МПа").arg(val, 0, 'f', 2);
}, this);
// Далее обычная работа с progressBar'ом
```

Comment: а если уже в дизайнере накидал progressBar ' ы ?? можно ли тогда работать через внешний функтор форматирования ?

Comment: @timob256, да, там где-то под правой кнопкой есть «Преобразовать в…»

Answer (score 1):

На фоне @Fat-Zer -а весьма плохой но простейший ответ на поставленный вопрос. @gdb спасибо за этот ответ.

```
void MainWindow::on_pB_DD1_valueChanged(int value)
{
     double i = value/100.0;
     ui->pB_DD1->setFormat(QString::number(i)+trUtf8("МПа"));
}
```